# In Umbraco, inline javascript turned to lowercase in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, umbraco, umbraco7

Using Umbraco 7.2, when i try to write javascript inline (on the template page) When i view the page it breaks, using chrome dev tools i noticed it is converting all the javascript to lowercase so ".addClass" becomes ".addclass" and doesn't get recognised.
Strangely this only seems to happen in chrome, in firefox and IE it displays correctly.

I know using inline javascript is not best practice for Umbraco, but can anyone tell me why it might be doing this?

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav-menu">
                <ul class="nav-menu-main">
                    <li><a href="/" class="nav-home glyphicon glyphicon-home"></a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">one</a><span></span>
                 <ul class="nav-menu-sub">
                @foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Site().adviserZone)
            {
                var linkUrl = (bool)item.isInternal ? Umbraco.NiceUrl(item.Value<int>("internal")) : item.link;
                var linkTarget = (bool)item.newWindow ? "_blank" : null;
                <li><a href="@linkUrl" target="@linkTarget">@item.caption</a></li>
            }  
                </ul>            
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="/">two</a><!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
                 <ul class="nav-menu-sub">
                @foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Site().knowledgeCentre)
            {
                var linkUrl = (bool)item.isInternal ? Umbraco.NiceUrl(item.Value<int>("internal")) : item.link;
                var linkTarget = (bool)item.newWindow ? "_blank" : null;
                <li><a href="@linkUrl" target="@linkTarget">@item.caption</a></li>
            }  
                </ul> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/partners">three</a><span></span>
                 <ul class="nav-menu-sub">
                @foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Site().partners)
            {
                var linkUrl = (bool)item.isInternal ? Umbraco.NiceUrl(item.Value<int>("internal")) : item.link;
                var linkTarget = (bool)item.newWindow ? "_blank" : null;
                <li><a href="@linkUrl" target="@linkTarget">@item.caption</a></li>
            }  
                </ul> 
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="/">four</a><span></span>
                 <ul class="nav-menu-sub">
                @foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Site().products)
            {
                var linkUrl = (bool)item.isInternal ? Umbraco.NiceUrl(item.Value<int>("internal")) : item.link;
                var linkTarget = (bool)item.newWindow ? "_blank" : null;
                <li><a href="@linkUrl" target="@linkTarget">@item.caption</a></li>
            }  
                </ul> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">five</a><span></span>
                 <ul class="nav-menu-sub">
                @foreach (var item in CurrentPage.Site().inTheNews)
            {
                var linkUrl = (bool)item.isInternal ? Umbraco.NiceUrl(item.Value<int>("internal")) : item.link;
                var linkTarget = (bool)item.newWindow ? "_blank" : null;
                <li><a href="@linkUrl" target="@linkTarget">@item.caption</a></li>
            }  
                </ul>  
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </nav>

        @{
           IPublishedContent current = (CurrentPage);
           Stack<dynamic> pages = new Stack<dynamic>();
           while (current.Level > 1)
          {
              pages.Push(current);
             current = current.Parent;
         }
        }
        <div class="breadcrumb-bar">
            <ul class="breadcrumbs container">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                @foreach (var page in pages)
                {
                    var cls = page.Id == CurrentPage.Id ? "current" : "";
               <li class="@cls"><a href="@page.Url">@page.Name.ToLower()</a></li>
              } 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
        <footer>
        </footer>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.2.3.2.js"></script>
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/main.js"></script>*@
    <script>
        var menuItem = $(".nav-menu-main > li > a");
        var subMenu = $(".nav-menu-sub")
        $(subMenu).mouseover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children(menuItem).addClass("hover-active");
        });
        $(subMenu).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().children(menuItem).removeClass("hover-active");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us the template code?

Comment: this has been bugging me for a couple of days, so i exported it to an external javascript file, and when i've tried to reimport it back into an inline script to replicate the bug it has fixed... Still trying to work out why this has happened, this problem of 'lower casing' my javascript has happened before on this project, but last time was when i was writing my script through visual studio.. I'm interested to know if anyone else has experienced this...
I can't understand why it would do this

Comment: The only thing that I could think of is that if you paste your code inside an element (like where the pipe is in this string <div |></div>) visual studio automatically turns it to lowercase because it's an attribute, or if you use ctrl+k+c and ctrl+k+u to comment / decomment code and by mistake you type ctrl+u (or maybe ctrl+k+u+u) that's the shortcut to make the selection all lowercase

Comment: We have spotted this issue too
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7//73111-preview-mode-makes-inline-javascript-lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in Umbraco where a script tag near the closing body tag would be forced to lowercase.

I have submitted a pull request to Umbraco today, https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/pull/926 so it should be fixed in a later release